# Math game for the kids

Tags: soft-question

On my spare time I am going to program a computer math game for 
the kids and their friends. I'm thinking about using plenty
of mathematical animations, pictures, fun facts, stories etc.
I want to make mathematics fun for them.

What areas of mathematics should i focus on?
Where are kids and young adults having the most trouble understanding the subject?

Comment: Python has plenty of math-based packages, I believe. I'm pretty sure the math software Sage is based on Python, so I would imagine you'll be fine.

Comment: Probably ask on www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @bleh I don't think you should be suggesting any alternate exchange/overflow websites that you're not significantly familiar with. I'm not sure this question really belongs anywhere on the network (but I don't know -- so I'm not recommending anything!)

Comment: The help center suggests matheducators.stackexchange.com for questions about teaching and pedagogy. Nontheless, *I* *don't* *know* *that* *site*, therefore *I* *don't* *know* if this would be on-topic there.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Ok, ty anyway, i try there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has many other packages. There are at least 300, and I'm sure a dozen or so of those packages have to do with math. Python has plenty of math in itself, so, I wouldn't worry about learning another language.